# Проблема со ссылками

Tags: php, ссылки

Здравствуйте!

Проблема, значит, в чем. Существует сайт, stavropolie.ru. При запросе в поисковике, например "стройматериалы из соломы ставрополье", получается такая ссылка "`http://vwstavropol.s...p?notion_id=781`", а должна быть - "`http://stavropolie.ru/notion.php?notion_id=781`", "строительные материалы из соломы ставрополье", получается такая ссылка "`http://klimatkontrol.stavropolie.ru/notion.php?notion_id=781`", а должна быть опять же такая - "`http://stavropolie.ru/notion.php?notion_id=781`".

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 1):

ну настроено так у вас, сделайте редирект в поддоменов на нужный домен и все.

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^http://vwstavropol.stavropolie.ru$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://stavropolie.ru/$1 [R=301,L]
```

ну примерно так, кое что дописать и будет работать :)
[redirect .htaccess](http://www.htaccess.net.ru/doc/Redirect/)

Comment: А можно поточнее... или пример какой нибудь...

Comment: обновил. смотри